# What's a simple way to define multiple jQuery.Callbacks() prerequisites?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the simplest way to define multiple jQuery.Callbacks() prerequisites?

```
// simple pubsub example
var pubsub=(function() {
    var callbacksObj={};
    return function(id){
        if(!id) throw 'callbacks requires an id';
        return (callbacksObj[id] = callbacksObj[id] || $.Callbacks('unique memory'));
    };
})();
function fn1(){
    console.log('fn1');
};
function fn2(){
    console.log('fn2');
};
function fn3(){
    console.log('fn3');
};

// subscribing
pubsub('foo').add(fn1);
pubsub('bar').add(fn2);
pubsub('foo','bar').add(fn3); // adding a function with multiple dependencies

// publishing
pubsub('foo').fire() // should only log 'fn1';
pubsub('bar').fire() // should log both 'fn2' AND 'fn3' since both have fired
```

I can see wrapping each added function in another function that checks each id's fired() state, though this seems like a common enough scenario that perhaps there's a simpler way I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `deferred` is what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

it looks like this:

`$.when(some_promise).then(some_callback)`

And you can have:

`$.when(some_promise, another_promise).then(some_callback)`

In this case `some_callback` will only be called if `some_promise` *and* `another_promise` have been resolved.

`deferred` basically just adds a level of abstraction to your asynchronous functions, making it easier to express the dependencies. I suppose your example would look like:

```
// simple pubsub example
var pubsub=(function() {
    var callbacksObj={};
    return function(id){
        if(!id) throw 'callbacks requires an id';
        return some_assynchrnous_function(id); // like $.ajax
    };
})();
function fn1(){
    console.log('fn1');
};
function fn2(){
    console.log('fn2');
};
function fn3(){
    console.log('fn3');
};

// subscribing
var foo = pubusb('foo');    // should return a deferred/promise
var bar = pubsub('bar');

$.when(foo).then(fn1);
$.when(bar).then(fn2);
$.when(foo, bar).then(fn3);
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct for jQuery, but you get the idea. I didn't find the jQuery API to make very much sense to me so I wrote my own :3

I find it useful to be able to make 'empty' deferred objects, then attaching a `done` handler to it, then passing the deferred object along to something that will eventually end up resolving it. I'm not sure if jQuery can do this.

It may seem a little daunting at first, but if you can wrap your head around it you can get so much awesomeness from this. Dependencies is a big one but scoping is also great, you can add multiple `done` handlers on multiple levels, one handler may handle the actual data, one handler may just be interested in when the handler finishes so you can show a loading bar etc.

Comment: Thanks Frits.  Just saw your response.  Marking it as answered as I reached the same conclusion separately.  As you said, decorating with multiple done handlers make for awesomeness.